# How to parse json file data as request parameter in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, api, automation, restsharp, xunit

I am using RestSharp along with C# Xnuit to automate API testing.

Currently i am creating string for request parameters as below.

```
string jsonString = @"{""customerName"": ""George Smith"", ""date"": ""2019-12-04""}";
var restRequest = restAPI.CreatePostRequest(jsonString);
```

Now instead of this i want create separate testdata.json file to add request parameters and use that file to create request. How to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a folder that is supposed to hold test data and then retrieve the file and read it into a string.

The LocateScriptsFolder starts at the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory and keeps walking up the path until it locates the script folder.

```
    public static DirectoryInfo LocateScriptsFolder(string baseDir)
    {
        var parent = Directory.GetParent(baseDir);
        if (parent.GetDirectories("DataFolder").Any())
        {
            return parent.GetDirectories("DataFolder").First();
        }
        return LocateScriptsFolder(parent.FullName);
    }
    var baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    var scripts = LocateScriptsFolder(baseDir);
    scripts.GetFiles("*.json").First();
    var json = File.ReadAllText(script.FullName);
```